# Google Analytics only recognizes when navigating directly or refreshing page

Tags: google-analytics

Google Analytics only recognizes a page view when:

a) visitor navigates directly to the page or
b) they refresh a page that has been navigated to indirectly

GA does not recognize a page view if navigated to a page through clicking a link on the website. E.g. if someone navigates directly to Home then clicks on navigation link to get to Services page, GA only recognizes Home. GA recognizes Services only if Services page is then refreshed.

**Edit**
First thought was caching header html (where GA code is located), but that can't be right. Have downloaded two new browsers and it does the same thing. GA code is on each page's individual header, so it is loading GA code for first time when navigating through in-page links on new browsers.

Any ideas of what could be going on?

Comment: what website is this on

Comment: avocadoanalytics.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that on `avocadoanalytics.com` when you click a link on that page, it does not actually go to that page, but loads the page content in the background and then inserts it into the current page, hence why GA does not say that you went to a page. however when you refresh, the site does load the page, so GA says you get a visit.

You can learn more about this here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: Thanks, but let me give you some more info. Before, using GA Univ code on site it recognized navigation as separate pages.  Now, switched to GA Tag Manager and not recognizing. So that can't be the answer, right? Something Tag Manager does differently than just standard GA code on a site.

Comment: You could use the code under implementation here https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages

Comment: that is GA code - which works fine. But I'd rather use Tag Manager.

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: Switched to Tag Manager - suddenly it only recognizes direct navigation or when pages refreshed. Why? How to make Tag Manager work?

Comment: have you tried reading the documentation? you probably haven't added the code correctly.